# Getting "NTFS5: No ang0" error message when booting Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, grub, dual-boot, boot-loader

I am getting the following message as shown in the link below when trying to boot into linux mint 13.

[image]

```
Try (hd0,0): NFTS5: No ang0
Try (hd0,1): NTFS5: No ang0
Try (hd0,2): NTFS5: No ang0
Try (hd0,3): Extended:
Try (hd0,4): NTFS5: No ang0
Try (hd0,5): Extended:
Try (hd0,5): EXT2:
```

I am dual booting Linux Mint with Windows 7.

I was able to boot Linux Mint when I last used it a month ago, but know I get the message show below. I haven't made any changes to the Linux Mint partition. Can anyone suggest how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This [Forum Post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=58701) may help.  I recently bought a new laptop with the new UEFI disklayout, and soon realized that the EFI boot tools that are usable in Windows7/8 are not up too par with even the Basic grub2.  It's much easier to:

1. Use your recovery media to boot into Windows.
2. Repair your EFI partition, using a method [like so](http://fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/#.Uz2NavldVqU).
3. Install a Recent version of a Debian Variant, such as Ubuntu or Mint, that includes UEFI Shim, in case something goes wrong in your boot sequence, and lastly
4. Use GRUB2 for your bootloader, and allow GRUB2 to perform the boot tasks.  Using os-prober, GRUB2 will detect a Windows partition and boot it normally

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Easy BCD.
2. Delete existing Linux entry.
3. Add new Linux entry.
4. Save and exit.

Comment: Saved and remembered me this simple solution! Thanks it works.

Answer (score -1):

1. Have you tried the other devices that it recommends?

   - If so, how did the system respond?
2. If you can make a live media and paste your configurations for your boot loader that would be very helpful as well.

   - Once booted into the live media `mount /dev/sdaX` (replacing X with the partition number that you root partition is on) and then the configuration should be in `/mnt/boot/<bootload>` (placement will change according to bootloader used, but it will be in that general area.
3. `fdisk -l` output

   - Include a brief description of the layout (e.g. Which is your root which is boot [if any].. and so on)

From the information that you've provided it simply looks as if your boot loader is configured incorrectly. How this happened? No clue, it's not my system. But sometimes having boot files are multiple disks can cause this, or windows just breaks the configuration since it doesn't know how to deal with it.

Enough guessing. Lets get some logs and some system output.